# What is the max value that we can use for ping timeout in socket io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Just wanted to know what is the highest value that we can set as ping timeout for a socket connection?
Also it would be helpful if it can be specified what is the ideal ping timeout for different scenarios to manage concurrency from creating small socket based games to creating chat application

Answer (score 0):

the max ping timeout is approx 4 billion years as  at that point the Sun will have consumed the entire planet, thus disconnecting the Internet connection.

for a game thats real time action like a first person shooter  , you probably dont want to go too much higher than 1-2 seconds or the lag causes graphic issues.

For connections to chat clients , especially modern chat protocols, the ideal timeout is probably best at under 90 seconds, but will still work even with a ping time of 2 years..

Ultimately though, light can travel around the earth twice in one second, so you wont see many ping times higher than 2 seconds unless you are trying to chat with someone on mars or via a 56k dialup modem